# Error al compilar en GCC linux

Tags: c, gcc

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
 {
    int a;
     a=50;

   //imprimo a
   printf("El valor de a: %i \n",a);
   printf("La dire de a: %i \n",&a);

   //creo 2 punteros
   int *p1, *p2;

  //p1 tiene de dato la direc de a (&a)
   p1=&a;

   //copio el dato de p1 en p2
   p2=p1;

   //imprimo p1
   printf("valor de p1: %i \n",p1);
   printf("Direccion de p1: %i \n",&p1);
   printf("Apunta p1: %i \n",*p1);

  //imprimo p2
  printf("valor de p2: %i \n",p2);
  printf("Direccion de p2: %i \n",&p2);
  printf("Apunta p2: %i \n",*p2);

  return 0; 
}
```

Al compilar desde la terminal de ubuntu  con gcc , me da un error :

[image: Imagen]

```
        punteros07.c: In function ‘main’:
      punteros07.c:12:27: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of 
      type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Direccion de a: %i \n",&a);
                             ^
      punteros07.c:24:26: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of 
      type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
      printf("valor de p1: %i \n",p1);
                           ^
      punteros07.c:25:30: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of 
      type ‘int’,  
      but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
      printf("Direccion de p1: %i \n",&p1);
                               ^
    punteros07.c:29:25: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type 
    ‘int’, 
    but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("valor de p2: %i \n",p2);
                         ^
    punteros07.c:30:29: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type 
    ‘int’, 
    but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("Direccion de p2: %i \n",&p2);
                             ^
```

Si lo compilo con el codeblocks funciona perfectamente,cual seria el error por el cual no puedo compilarlo en gcc ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo que obtienes no son errores, son advertencias, tu programa va a funcionar de todas formas aunque puede que no produzca el resultado correcto, pero ten en cuenta que un `int` no es lo mismo que un `int *`.

Actualmente pasas por parametro a `printf` un puntero, su dirección y el valor al que apunta.

Para mostrar punteros correctamente utiliza el especificador de formato `%p` de la siguiente forma:

```
printf("El puntero: %p\n", p1); // Muestra la dirección de p1.
```

Esto pasa porque las direcciones de memoria son de distintos tamaños dependiendo de la plataforma y `%i` o `%d` esperan un número entero con signo por parametro y no un número sin signo.

Pasa lo mismo con la siguiente instrucción:

```
printf("Direccion de p2: %i \n",&p2);
```

Al utilizar el operador `&` en un puntero, vuelves su tipo en *un puntero de un puntero*, es decir, `int *` no es lo mismo que `int **`, este último se utiliza para emular lo que es "Pasar por referencia" en C.

Si haces:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void asignar_NULL(int **ref) {
    if (ref && *ref)  // Aseguremonos de que el puntero existe.
        free(*ref)
    *ref = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Colocando a INT\n");
    int *INT = malloc(sizeof(int));
    asignar_NULL(&INT); // pasamos a INT por "referencia".
    *INT = 4; // Error! INT ahora es NULL, segmentation fault aquí.
    return 0;
}
```

Fijate que he declarado un puntero a `int` y lo he convertido en un _puntero a puntero de `int` y así poder utilizar esa variable.

Vease:

- [Especificadores de formato](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/printf_format)
- [Punteros](http://lsi.vc.ehu.es/pablogn/docencia/manuales/C/Punteros%20en%20C.html)